# Automated post to my own fb fan page - Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException:

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've read what seems to be every post on stack related to this topic but nothing seems to work.

I've gone to the Graph explorer on the fb developers page used the Get Access Token button, (making sure to select the parameters needed - user_likes,publish_actions,email,offline_access,publish_stream,manage_pages)then used that to create a long term access token with the following link: inserting/replacing

```
<MYAPPID>,<MYSECRETID>,<SHORT_TERM_TOKEN>
```

with the real stuff in:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=<MYAPPID>&client_secret=<MYSECRETID>&fb_exchange_token=<SHORT_TERM_TOKEN>
```

Got my `<TWO_MONTH_TOKEN>`

Tried now to implement into code:

```
require "fb_src/facebook.php";


    $config = array('appId' => '<MYAPPID>','secret' => '<MYSECRETID>');

    $params = array('scope'=>'user_likes,publish_actions,email,offline_access,publish_stream,manage_pages');
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if($facebook->getUser()) {
    try {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
                        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
                        error_log($e->getType());
                        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

    }    

$page_id = "<MY_FANPAGE_ID>";
            $page_access_token = "";
            $result = $facebook->api("/me/accounts");
            foreach($result["data"] as $page) {
                if($page["id"] == $page_id) {
                $page_access_token = $page["access_token"];
                //echo '<br>';
                //echo "2. ".$page_access_token;
                break;
                    }
                }


        $args = array(
            'access_token'  => '<TWO_MONTH_TOKEN>',
            'message'       => "my short message",
            'name' => "name of post",
            'link' => "http://example.com/",
            'picture' => "http://example.com/images/fbobimgSV403.jpg",
            'actions' => array(
            'name' => 'page name',
            'link' => "http://example.com/page_name"
            )

        );
       $post = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
```

What really has me in a twist is that this exact code worked at 2am this morning about 20 times while testing it out.. Then it stopped when I logged out to see if I could get it to work while not logged in. I've since logged in again and repeated the process to no avail. The access token is still good for 2 months. (Yes, i've tried clearing the cache and deleting cookies.)

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in /public_html/facebook/fb_src/base_facebook.php on line 1249
```

also I should point out that `$user = $facebook->getUser();` returns 0 every time.

I'm hoping that someone has successfully done this and can steer me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: "The access token is still good for 2 months.". Can you debug your user access token at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to confirm it's still valid at this point?

Comment: Just debugged again and it said it will expire "Never".

Comment: So you can successfully post to the page wall before logout?